# How to swap Country and State/province fields in Billing informations

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

How can i swap the fields Country and State/province in the "Billing Information" form during checkout?
Ubercart 3 and Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Ubercart 3.0 the ucstore module was updated and now in the admin page

Store > Configuration > Countries and addresses > Address fields

You can drag the field in the position you Want.
Thank to Ubercart mantainers.